# HTTP Get Node JS to parse using document elements

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I have written some javascript that goes to a page and returns the data from the site, however, I would like to get specific elements off this html site and use functions like document.getElementById. How can I use that sort of functionality here? Currently, the console.log(chunk) simply spits out the entire body of html, I want to be able to parse that.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/news'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk);

    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code production! Please show us what you have tried!

Comment: I have tried. All I am able to do is print the body, and am not sure how I select specific elements.

Comment: You already said how to: getElementById

Answer (score 0):

There are many npm modules to perform the same, here are some

1.[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

2.[jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)